# How to create an array using php with identical values but different id without using loop

Tags: php, arrays

this question is for ask if there is any better way to create an array with values like that

```
array(
    [0] => 'course_25_expires',
    [1] => 'course_31_expires',
    [2] => 'course_43_expires',
    [3] => 'course_45_expires',
    [4] => 'course_48_expires',
    [5] => 'course_67_expires'
)
```

by just using another array that can have only the IDs for that records as the one that following:

```
array(
    [0] => 25,
    [1] => 31,
    [2] => 43,
    [3] => 45,
    [4] => 48,
    [5] => 67
)
```

is there any kind of walker in PHP that can use a kind of "string template" and an array with values and produce an array with mix of the values and the template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_map()` and an anonymous function to do this:

```
$output = array_map(
    function ($item) { return "course_{$item}_expires"; },
    $data
);
```